# Is there a way to have a global variable in a stackview?

Tags: flash, apache-flex, adobe, global, textfield

I have a stackview of textfields and when I type into the text field I want it to update on each stackview "page", kind of like a global variable, maybe even using a global variable. How could I go by doing so?

Comment: Any luck with this? Try posting some more code and we can work something out

Answer (score 3):

Here's my solution using a field variable and some text inputs
Script:

```
[Bindable] protected var s:String = "";
```

MXML:

```
<mx:ViewStack id="textStack">
    <mx:HBox label="1">
        <mx:TextInput id="ti1" text="{this.s}" change="this.s = ti1.text" />
    </mx:HBox>
    <mx:HBox label="2">
        <mx:TextInput id="ti2" text="{this.s}" change="this.s = ti2.text" />
    </mx:HBox>
</mx:ViewStack>
```

Let me know if this works for you!